# Continuously updating data web scraped

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to car e-commerce application using Android Java. I've already scraped data on a  car website but my issue is how would I continuously update the data being scraped to get newer cars on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

couldn't you just run the webscraper periodically using a timed process.

Comment: How would I do it?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this and it depends upon what systems you have available.   You can time aws lambda functions or schedule tasks using an access database.   Perhaps an easy way for you to start would be adjust your web scraper so that it has an infinite loop that scrapes the data, then perhaps rests for a while and  tests for some signal to exit the loop.   You could then just leave it running on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Use generater with timer hopefully it will continue updating data.

Comment: How would I do that?